# I have estimated time on a job but when I add the employee's (in this case 2) hours, it will duplicate the estimated

Tags: sql-server

I have estimated time on a job but when I add the employee's (in this case 2) hours, it will duplicate the estimated. I need to divide by the number of results (maybe employee records) to get the correct answer.

SQL pull from database.

```
SELECT
     LaborDtl.JobNum,
     LaborDtl.ClockInDate,
     LaborDtl.OprSeq,
     EmpBasic.Name,
     (LaborDtl.LaborHrs) as [TotalHrs],
     ((JobOper.EstSetHours + JobOper.EstProdHours) / (COUNT (EmpBasic.Name))) as [TotEstHrs],
     LaborDtl.ResourceGrpID
FROM Erp.LaborDtl

left outer JOIN Erp.JobOper ON
   JobOper.JobNum = LaborDtl.JobNum
   AND JobOper.OprSeq = LaborDtl.OprSeq
JOIN Erp.EmpBasic ON
   EmpBasic.EmpID = LaborDtl.EmployeeNum
WHERE LaborDtl.Complete = '1'
   AND LaborDtl.ClockInDate = '2019-7-1'
   AND LaborDtl.ResourceGrpID = '5-XM-C'
   AND LaborDtl.JobNum = 'PA16742'

GROUP BY 
LaborDtl.JobNum,
LaborDtl.ClockInDate,
LaborDtl.OprSeq,
EmpBasic.Name,
LaborDtl.LaborHrs,
JobOper.EstSetHours,
JobOper.EstProdHours,
LaborDtl.EmployeeNum,
LaborDtl.ResourceGrpID

JobNum  ClockInDate OprSeq  Name        TotalHrs  TotEstHrs ResourceGrpID
pa16742 2019-07-01  20      Jerry Adam  1.6300    5.00      5-XM-C
PA16742 2019-07-01  20      Xue Lee     2.68000   5.00      5-XM-C
```

In this case, the TotEstHrs should be 2.5 on each line.

Comment: Mistagged? SQL tag is meant for ANSI/ISO standard SQL code this SQL dialect seams to be SQL Server code?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
 ((JobOper.EstSetHours + JobOper.EstProdHours) / SUM(COUNT(EmpBasic.Name)) 
    OVER ()) as [TotEstHrs],
```

It adds the count over all the rows and then does the division.

Comment: perfect!! Last question, how to I round to the nearest 2 decimals in that results?

Comment: After reviewing, I am getting some funny results. I have another job with 2 employees where the total estimated hours are 6 and when using the formula it give me .461538xxxxxx in both results.

Comment: @CliftonKeathley . . . Perhaps you want `over (partition by jobnum)` rather than `over ()`.

Comment: I think I got it by oprseq! Thank you all so much!